# Count occurrences of each value for every specific id

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a customer table like this:

```
trans-id | cust-id | trans-type | amount
----------------------------------------
   t1    |   c1    |    buy     |  700
   t2    |   c2    |    sell    |  200
   t3    |   c1    |    sell    |  400
   t4    |   c3    |    buy     |  900
   t5    |   c2    |    sell    |  100
```

I am trying to group up each of this customer with each of their type and amount. Below is the expected table that I want to get.

```
cust-id | num_of_trans | num_of_buy | num-of-sell | total_amount | total_buy | total_sell|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   c1   |      2       |     1      |      1      |     1100     |    700    |    400
   c2   |      2       |     0      |      2      |     300      |    0      |    300
   c3   |      1       |     1      |      0      |     900      |    900    |    0
```

I already try to use 'group by', but i can only get num_of_trans and total_amount. I have no idea how to split them as buy and sell. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incidentally, including '-' in column names is not smart.

Comment: thats should be '_'. My mistake..